# How can I permit SSH connection terminal programs to access Camera?

Tags: terminal, permission, ssh, catalina, camera

I'm connecting to my macOS 10.15.1 device over SSH via PuTTY on a Windows computer to run a terminal program, [imagesnap](https://github.com/rharder/imagesnap), that attempts to use the MacBook's camera.

When I ran the program locally on command-line on a Terminal the first time I got a permission pop-up that allowed me to give Terminal access to Camera in the Security & Privacy settings.

When I run the same program on command-line via an SSH connection the program aborts without successfully taking a photo, and I receive no permission request for Camera access.

When I look at the section Camera in the Security & Privacy settings after trying to run the program using SSH there are no entries besides Terminal, which was already given access. Terminal is shown marked as having Camera access, so it and SSH programs are separate considerations for Security & Privacy.

How do I give my SSH connection programs Camera access?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the list of permissions in System Preferences => Security & Privacy. Select the Privacy tab and then choose Camera in the list on the left. You can then checkmark the apps on the right that you want to have access to the camera.

If you have previously denied access to a program, it should appear here where you can checkmark it to allow access again.

As you're running a command line program from within the Terminal, it is Terminal.app that appears in the list on the right - and this is the program that needs to be checkmarked.

UPDATE: After your edit I realize that your problem is specifically when run via SSH, and not in general via the command line. In that case try prefixing your command with the "open" command.

For example like this:

```
open -a /Path/To/imagesnap /Path/To/imagesnap
```

Comment: When viewing System Preferences => Security & Privacy => Camera, only the Terminal appears in the list, and it has been checked off as yes for access to the Camera. I haven't denied SSH programs access to the camera in the past, and don't receive a pop-up requesting Camera access privileges when running the program that attempts to open the Camera via SSH, so Terminal remains the only entry in the Camera privacy list.

Comment: Yes, then you have set everything up correctly!

Comment: For sessions logged in from remote (which seems to be what the OP is doing) Terminal isn't involved so granting Camera access to Terminal won't help.

Comment: Yes, my issue is using the Camera from programs over an SSH connection. A local Terminal behaves as expected. I've updated my post to make this as clear as possible.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem now - please try the suggestion I have added (using the open command to force it opened as a GUI application).

Comment: I've tried running `open -a /usr/local/bin/imagesnap /usr/local/bin/imagesnap` from my SSH connection and received the following output: `LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /usr/local/bin/imagesnap with error -10810 for the file /usr/local/bin/imagesnap.`. My [cursory research](https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues/66#issuecomment-323288872) suggests this involves the Launch Services framework.

Comment: Try just "open /usr/local/bin/imagesnap" -- same problem?

Comment: Running  `open /usr/local/bin/imagesnap` opens and closes a terminal on the MacBook display! Thanks for the help. This is progress, so next I will look into how to pass the command-line options via `open` on SSH to run `imagesnap` to attempt to use the camera.

Comment: Update: by running `open '/usr/local/bin/imagesnap' --args '-w 1 mysnap.png -v'`, the arguments being the `imagesnap` commands to take a photo, I notice my MacBook's Camera light turning on. However, searching with `find` I cannot locate any file matching `mysnap.png` and without access to the terminal output of `imagesnap` since it was launched this way I'm unsure how to confirm or deny if the SSH program has access to the Camera. Terminal is still the only entry in "Security & Privacy" => "Camera".

Comment: You just need to specify the full path to mysnap.png. I..e replace "mysnap.png" in your command line with something like "/Users/myuser/mysnap.png". Then the file should end up in a predictable spot!

Comment: @jksoegaard thanks again for all the help. I ran `sudo find / -name mysnap.png` so the file was not saved anywhere locally. When I ran `'/usr/local/bin/imagesnap' --args '-w 1 /Users/esarkis/Downloads/mysnap.png -v'` to save the image to my download folder but there is still no image file.

Comment: Try modifying imagesnap to save its error messages to a file - then you can see what happens. Might be worth contacting the developer?

Comment: Instead of modifying imagesnap I'm trying an alternative better-established command line image tool, [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). I run it locally from my Terminal and it works as expected. However, via SSH it aborts with code `10780`.
The command is:
`ffmpeg -ss 0.5 -f avfoundation -pix_fmt uyvy422 -framerate 30 -i "0" -t 1 -frames:v 1 /Users/esarkis/ffmpegcapture.jpg`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102088/discussion-between-esarkis-and-jksoegaard).